# Remotely running Acrobat Distller via powershell command line

Tags: powershell

I have a task to remotely run Acrobat Distller (AD) remotely.

I was able to locally run AD in the command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\acrodist.exe" /O $OutputFolder $InputFolder\test.ps
```

I tried invoking the same command using powershell:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\acrodist.exe" /O $OutputFolder $InputFolder\test.ps'}
```

When ran, the powershell command did prompt any error BUT it did not generate the expected PDF output as well.

Can I get some assistance on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Before trying to invoke with powershell.exe, make sure `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\acrodist.exe" /O $OutputFolder $InputFolder\test.ps` works by itself in a powershell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `$using:OutputFolder` and `$using:InputFolder`.

Normally, powershell variables are only set for your session and don't carry over to remote servers. The `$Using:` format allows you to do this with `Invoke-Command`.